# multiarch for armhf in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: arm

Can anyone guide me on how to set up my x86_64 Ubuntu 13.10 for building armhf libraries and executables ?

I have already  installed `g++-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf`, `gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `pkg-config-arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

And this allowed me to get the compilers (`/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8` and /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 ) for building stuff, but now I want to set up the system in order to install the libraries that I need with the dependencies (like `uuid-dev:armhf` for example).

So I run `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` and I modify the source lists and update, like so:

`deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted`

`deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports saucy main restricted`

`apt-get update`

But when I try to install uuid-dev:armhf, I have unmet dependencies, and I don't know how to solve the problem.

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: uuid-dev:armhf : Depends: libc6-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed or libc-dev:armhf Depends: libuuid1:armhf (= 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu9) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: I've already read a bit on the subject and here's how I proceed. I run `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` and `apt-get update`. and `apt-get install uuid-dev:armhf`. But it is not found, so I modify my apt source lists `deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports saucy main restricted`. But then my package have unmet dependencies...

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 uuid-dev:armhf : Depends: libc6-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed or
                           libc-dev:armhf
                  Depends: libuuid1:armhf (= 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu9) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since I have a specific problem which is the depency resolution for the installation of `uuid-dev:armhf`

Comment: perhaps update your question.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen done.

Comment: The root of problem is some changes in ubuntu's servers.